# How can I enable DKIM email verification on windows server 2019 for sending DKIM verified email via SMTP service?

Tags: ssl, smtp, windows-server-2019, dkim, smtp-auth

I am sending activation and verification emails from my domain : https://www.monstermmorpg.com/

Recently I have moved to a new installation

The new server is : Windows Server 2019

How can I set a proper DKIM?

Moreover, gmail tells that the message is not encrypted

How can I encrypt messages?

I have thoroughly searched the internet and I couldn't find how to send email by SMTP when SSL is enabled

Looking for help thank you

This is my current C# code to send email

```
            using (MailMessage Email = new MailMessage(new MailAddress("noreply@monstermmorpg.com", srFrom), new MailAddress(srEmailAddress)))
        {
            Email.IsBodyHtml = true;
            Email.SubjectEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            Email.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            Email.Subject = srSubject;
            Email.ReplyTo = new MailAddress("admin@monstermmorpg.com", "MonsterMMORPG Administrator");
            using (AlternateView textPart = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(srBodyText, Encoding.UTF8, "text/plain"))
            {
                using (AlternateView htmlPart = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(srBodyHTML, Encoding.UTF8, "text/html"))
                {
                    textPart.TransferEncoding = System.Net.Mime.TransferEncoding.QuotedPrintable;
                    Email.AlternateViews.Add(textPart);

                    htmlPart.TransferEncoding = System.Net.Mime.TransferEncoding.QuotedPrintable;
                    Email.AlternateViews.Add(htmlPart);

                    using (SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("127.0.0.1", 25))
                    {
                        smtpClient.Send(Email);                            
                        return "True";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

The received email source code from gmail

```
    Delivered-To: monstermmorpg@gmail.com
Received: by 2002:a2e:3217:0:0:0:0:0 with SMTP id y23csp506469ljy;
        Fri, 14 May 2021 09:06:00 -0700 (PDT)
X-Google-Smtp-Source: ABdhPJzjZd6rMp/pnpxKsq1L06bwDvzbj8muKWN6+nFTLZU75Q7umGzQxkkil5RdVKUXcPvQCYe+
X-Received: by 2002:a67:f612:: with SMTP id k18mr36628964vso.14.1621008359976;
        Fri, 14 May 2021 09:05:59 -0700 (PDT)
ARC-Seal: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; t=1621008359; cv=none;
        d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        b=MfAvouyS6gARsLUkbkExyiliKm5JTjKiQyJneWOJ+ClrDqYnHYAnOR9+sd5DGHqAHQ
         B1uFRt+e8zPmi9BjiMrlzmU6vbBduXIe5XqpuZln9iUj6p3UvzM5RYwLfLgWru2kiU7L
         4JHw/qL0+u7EU2/7ONHY5OtzU6ky8y2zgHiBC+cymThrA/yrgf248TWxAjQ0kHbKggbD
         EeXPUmBEwZTYAYlI1BfRxeb3vMDd6fxddDuE9H2caU6FHmD2xZ/kqBsVYbAKIlb2kZsn
         wvL8cPoGL8PhoH+zW/SqSzjLdb4lxHqdmucUYlQDOKXhtYOWrmwGbTv5p3U5QvgBG7+R
         +0Qg==
ARC-Message-Signature: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        h=message-id:subject:date:reply-to:to:from:mime-version;
        bh=pl1glJA514sUYwdSYbJnqcj6IappZiIhLxbY8IS1skY=;
        b=gMouTK8xFFFUh2FegtyhVHu6EDZetSBQpyXKGTkzekmkQAMyv7GS3id5eC1hpxkOPI
         mMogftz7u7zVWHXxJld5AZwmdXAEyngNSQpRd1ejYPnLLihZ+4vnC25TMOSlDR4XSrV/
         EPfLkTAASP/+nMeNMBOkaZ04BHobfE4YOWaelRDdKJMfsIv/Q7kUlD2+x8sYIP5gYH1A
         IH3nxYIvc1krQhQiFapzplAaLTuw45JU514M2UHwxv48uqZsSo6xvM/66PVL8a4AM9QY
         oMZRFrNZbVs/jHOmfo7NmbhQKspmU6piBeikxXc62gEZrZscTjj1CnF1ExDOBYU4VTaR
         rClA==
ARC-Authentication-Results: i=1; mx.google.com;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of noreply@monstermmorpg.com designates 198.154.81.18 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=noreply@monstermmorpg.com
Return-Path: <noreply@monstermmorpg.com>
Received: from WIN-NKJ7NU5TC3R ([198.154.81.18])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTP id w2si4313304uau.70.2021.05.14.09.05.59
        for <monstermmorpg@gmail.com>;
        Fri, 14 May 2021 09:05:59 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of noreply@monstermmorpg.com designates 198.154.81.18 as permitted sender) client-ip=198.154.81.18;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of noreply@monstermmorpg.com designates 198.154.81.18 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=noreply@monstermmorpg.com
Received: from WIN-NKJ7NU5TC3R ([127.0.0.1]) by WIN-NKJ7NU5TC3R with Microsoft SMTPSVC(10.0.17763.1697);
     Fri, 14 May 2021 16:05:59 +0000
MIME-Version: 1.0
From: MonsterMMORPG <noreply@monstermmorpg.com>
To: monstermmorpg@gmail.com
Reply-To: MonsterMMORPG Administrator <admin@monstermmorpg.com>
Date: 14 May 2021 16:05:59 +0000
Subject: MonsterMMORPG Email Verification - Account Activation
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=--boundary_0_1f9b8fcb-6eb3-4f2d-903e-a44c9cf7ecbf
Return-Path: noreply@monstermmorpg.com
Message-ID: <WIN-NKJ7NU5TC3RaJiR00000002@WIN-NKJ7NU5TC3R>
X-OriginalArrivalTime: 14 May 2021 16:05:59.0129 (UTC) FILETIME=[077B7C90:01D748DB]

----boundary_0_1f9b8fcb-6eb3-4f2d-903e-a44c9cf7ecbf
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

CeFurkan Welcome to MonsterMMORPG
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The `Received: ... with Microsoft SMTPSVC(10.0.17763.1697);` suggests you are using **IIS SMTP**.

- As IIS SMTP is from IIS 6.0 (code name "Duct Tape", included with Windows Server 2003) and not updated since, it [does not support DKIM](https://forums.iis.net/t/1239563.aspx), which has been produced afterwards ([released in 2005](http://www.dkim.org/Misc/Press%20Release%20July-2005.html), [first RFC from 2007](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4870)).
- The outboud TLS encryption (which is not a message but a *transit* encryption!) is feasible through:

  1. Internet Information Services (IIS) 6.0 Manager
  2. [SMTP Virtual Server #1] Properties
  3. Delivery
  4. Outbound Security...
  5. [x] TLS encryption

  [image: IIS SMTP Outbound TLS]

However, **it would be much better to let a fully functional email server like Microsoft Exchange or Postfix handle both DKIM and TLS**. Without the intermediate IIS SMTP, using the [SmtpClient Class](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient?view=net-5.0), you could either send the message unencrypted on a local network or utilize STARTTLS from the [SmtpClient.EnableSsl Property](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient.enablessl?view=net-5.0):

```
using (SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.example.com", 25))
{
    smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
    smtpClient.Send(Email);                            
    return "True";
}
```